# Scan network with Linux kernel command

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, ip, nmap

Does Linux kernel provide some utility familiar to `nmap` for simple network scanning to discover attached nodes?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for; you want the _kernel_ itself to scan for hosts?  That's... not normal.  The `nmap` command exists on Linux.

Comment: I mean command which is shipped with any Linux distribution.

Comment: Debian and variants, RedHat and variants.... pretty much any mainstream Linux distro has nmap.  It may not install by default (depending on what options you pick) but an `apt` or `yum` command can install it easily enough.

Answer (score 0):

Ifconfig to find the IP of access point, then 
nmap -sn < ip addr. of AP >/24
This will list all devices connected to AP and the open ports.

Comment: If there's an AP and if the network is a /24...